# How to import certificate into JVM

Tags: java, certificate

I have a problem while I try yo import a certificate into JVM.

So I have write this command:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias HEALTHNETBR -file testedoCA.cer -keystore keystore_healthnetbr.jks -storepass changeit
```

If I try to run this command, I have this error message:

```
Errore keytool: java.lang.Exception: Le chiavi pubbliche nella risposta e nel ke
ystore non corrispondono
```

Comment: And what's that in English? And what part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Are you trying to add a new trusted certificate or are you trying to add the reply to a certificate request?  If it is the former then it is failing because there is already a key in the keystore named HEALTHNETBR.  If it is the latter then it is failing because the response you are trying to add does not seem to match any request generated for HEALTHNETBR.